# Python/wxpython app shows error while shutting down Windows

Tags: python, wxpython, py2exe

I have wxpython multi threaded app, bundled using py2exe, that keep running silently as a task-bar application under windows system tray. When I shutdown Windows, it shows following error message:

[Error screen http://devzila.com/error.jpg](http://devzila.com/error.jpg)

Comment: I don't know what can it be. But when system is closing it ask programs to close yourself and programs can close opened files, free memory, clear other stuff. Maybe you need some function which catch some event from system and than it can stop threads and do other stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to figure it out:
wx.EVT_END_SESSION is fired when windows try to close your application during  shutdown.

```
wx.GetApp().Bind(wx.EVT_END_SESSION, self.onClose)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind `wx.EVT_CLOSE` event for your application frame. In the callback function end all threads.

Comment: wx.EVT_CLOSE event is not fired during Windows shutdown but wx.EVT_END_SESSION is. Thanks anyway for pointing me in right direction.

Comment: Weird. I have to try out. I thought that whenever anything tries to close the frame, `wx.EVT_CLOSE` is fired. Did you correctly bind it to the frame? Just curious.